# What is the difference between “ti amo” and “ti voglio bene”?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Can we use “*ti amo*” for expressing love between siblings?

And we use “*ti voglio bene*” for expressing love between two passionate lovers?

Comment: I wouldn't: StackExchange sites are not intended to express opinions.

Comment: Talking about these two expressions, that Italian derives almost identical from Latin, *amare* and *bene velle*, how not to let Catullus speak ([Catul. LXXII][1]; and [here][2] for a commented English translation). [1]:http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0003%3Apoem%3D72
[2]:https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/The_Poetry_of_Gaius_Valerius_Catullus/72

Comment: (I slightly wonder who took the liberty of commuting my answer into a comment, and why)

Comment: I don't know who did that, but it makes sense, it's a comment. It's not abusive, quite the opposite: it's good moderation.

Comment: @PietroMajer: It is indeed a comment, and an interesting one at that, but does not provide an answer to the question, as it stands.

Comment: ok... maybe you could have made this remark as  a comment below my answer, so that I could have edited accordingly. You could also have downvoted it as not useful, of course. No problem.

Comment: @DaG Anyway, I really intended my post as an answer, not a side remark. My point was  that the difference between "amare" and "voler bene" is not, of course,  something specific of Italian, as the corresponding expressions exist in Latin, French, Italian, &c, with identical meaning.

Comment: Therefore if we are interested in the difference between these two concepts, the best is to go to the origin of European literature. In particular, Catullus' view has of course influenced all subsequent tradition. Therefore, in order to answer the OP, I deem the above Catul.72  more valuable  than my personal opinion about these two expressions (and the personal opinions of the other posters, with all due respect).

Comment: @PietroMajer: I agree, the history of the difference between the two notions in other times and languages is fascinating, but it is less than useful if one doesn't know the difference itself, here, now and in Italian language, and that is what the OP asked. I am not a moderator, but I'm sure a complete answer including this material but within the context of present-day meaning of Italian word *amare* and *volere bene* would be welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even though the verb *amare* is supposed to cover all meanings implied by the English verb *to love*, this is not how it is currently used. You would still say like this:

> Ama il prossimo tuo come te stesso.
>
> You shall love your neighbour as yourself.

You would start to sound slightly awkward, but still not necessarily incestuous, with a sentence like the following:

> Amo mia sorella.
>
> I love my sister.

But the serious problem arises with *ti amo*. This is a fixed way of saying *I love you* in a romantic sense, notwithstanding a long tradition of poor translations in movies. There are teens using the sentence in a "creative" way, like *ti amo come amico* or *ti amo di bene*, but it's more a way of being silly or overly sentimental or it's just a way of mocking wanna-be boyfriends being "friendzoned".

If you care for somebody in a non-romantic sense, go for the standard

> Ti voglio bene.
>
> I care for you.

This can be used in a romantic relationship, in order to highlight the more altruistic, tender (perhaps... extra-sexual?) side of the feeling felt for the other person.

> Ti amo, ma ti voglio anche molto bene.
>
> I'm in love with you, but I also care for you.

Actually, you could contrast *amore* e *voler bene*:

> "Ti voglio bene ma non ti amo più", [un libro di Andrew G. Marshall](http://www.ibs.it/code/9788879727006/marshall-andrew-g-/voglio-bene-non.html)
>
> "I Love You But I'm Not in Love with You", [a book by Andrew G. Marshall](http://andrewgmarshall.com/book/i-love-you-but-im-not-in-love-with-you-seven-steps-to-saving-your-relationship/)

Don't be misled by the last example, though: *to be in love* is not always translated as *amare*, because the Italian language often uses *essere innamorato* as opposed to *amare* to express the nuanced difference between being in love and loving. The point here is that the underlying implication of using *innamoramento* vs *amore* by many speakers is that there are two distinct phases of romantic love: the early, exhilarating stage and the subsequent developments. I don't believe that this distinction is as popular in English-speaking cultures where you are expected to *fall in love* and then stay... down there. Actually, the two-stage theory has supporters everywhere but not all languages have it embedded like Italian.

Summing up:

- *voler bene* = non-romantic altruistic love, caring for somebody
- *amare* = romantic love (in general or later, deeper stage of it) or old-fashioned description of caring for somebody
- *essere innamorati* = romantic love (in general or earlier, honeymoon-like stage of it) or infatuation of any kind

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible to use "TI AMO" between siblings but normally it's used between lovers.

There isn't a specific environment where use only "TI AMO" or only "TI VOGLIO BENE". Maybe, it's possible to tell that I use "TI VOGLIO BENE" when I'd like put in evidence that I want give you something and I hope that you are fine. More times it's used by parents for their children, it's used between friends, ... Using "TI VOGLIO BENE" there is one I and one you but it's not necessary that there is one we.

I use "TI AMO" when I'd like to put in evidence that I need you to be fine and of course I want that you are fine to so that I'm fine. Using "TI AMO" it's how there isn't one I and one you but one we.

Answer (score 5):

"TI AMO" has a strong meaning. It's used between lovers, but there are many forms of love. A parent can say "TI AMO" to its child. When we say "TI AMO" it means the we are strongly linked to that person, we care care about he/she as ourself or more.
"TI VOGLIO BENE" has no romantic meaning. It's less strong than "TI AMO", even if emotions are always involved. It means: I care about you and I wish you all the best.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use "TI AMO" for siblings, but it will sound very strange.
It's used for lovers, or between a child and a parent, or for other few special occasions ("Gesù ti ama", "Jesus loves you")

"TI AMO" is a very strong statement: Instead, "TI VOGLIO BENE" could be use for a frendship relations, and no one will ever think that the people who said you "TI VOGLIO BENE" il your lover... but if somen